# Graph embeddings on an orientable and nonorientable surface

Tags: graph-theory, surfaces, non-orientable-surfaces

Let $G$ be a graph of orientable genus $M$ and nonorientable genus $N$ where $M\ne 0\ne N$.  If we embed $G$ into an orientable surface of genus $M$ and a nonorientable surface of genus $N$ such that neither embedding contain an edge crossing, will the faces of the two embeddings necessarily be nonisomorphic?  As in, will the edges of the two embeddings determine different faces?

Comment: What do you mean with nonisomorphic/different faces? They live on different surfaces so they are different right? Their boundary is topologically a circle, hence the face is topologically a ball in both cases. Is it about the number of incident vertices?

Comment: I was thinking that what determines a face on a surface is a cycle of edges.  If you have a graph $G$ embedded on an orientable and nonorientable surface, the faces could be identified by cycles of edges.  My thinking is that if one were to do this, the cycles used to determine the faces on the two surfaces would necessarily be different.

Comment: My claim about the face being a ball is false I guess. Anyway, what you do is: the faces in the embedding determine a set of cycles of the graph and you want to know if these sets are necessarily different for directed and undirected surfaces, right?

Comment: Yes.  This is my question stated more elegantly.  I guess the only issue with the part "different for directed and undirected surfaces" is that an orientable surface of genus $n$ is in some sense contained within a nonorientable surface of genus $2n +1$, so any graph that can be embedded in an orientable surface of genus $n$ can be embedded in a nonorientable surface of genus $2n + 1$ in such a way that the faces will determine the same sets of cycles.

Comment: After thinking about it, the orientable genus of $K_7$ is $1$ and the nonorientable genus is at least $3$, according to a response I got on a previous question on this site. This tells me you could probably embed $K_7$ in the nonorientable surface of genus $3$ in the same way you could embed it in the torus.

Answer (score 1):

$K_7$ which has orientable genus $1$ and nonorientable genus $3$ is a counterexample.